# Visual Studio - Cannot choose UWP Anniversary Build SDK (10.0.14393)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I've got the problem, that I dont can choose a higher Build by setting up a project. I have reinstall VS. Remove all folders in appdata and program files. Restart the PC. Update 3 is installed...

[image]

[image]

Comment: just wanted to confirm the issue - I have reinstalled VS yesterday and had the same "surprise", moreover VS marked all my Anniversary Build targeted projects as "incompatible" with current VS version - had to manually edit target version to have them opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem long back(VS2015 Update3 version) after that I have Installed SDK separately & It was working fine.

May be you can try same.

Comment: so uninstall the SDKs with the VSInstaller and manually install them from msdn? I will try when Im home. Thanks

Comment: Control panel uninstall the SDK version , not VS & Install SDK separately .

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk